# jquery live(on) click doesn't trigger on live content with IE8

Tags: jquery, events, internet-explorer-8, click, live

I've tried this issue with version 1.9.1 and 1.10.1.

```
$(document).on("click", '.a-radio-button', function (event) {
```

It is working only when first load of dom. But when I update the content with ajax it is not triggering. Every major browser has no issue, but this doesn't work in ie8.

**Edit**: I've tried with these elements: radio, checkbox, button.

Comment: I'm guessing at least jQuery 1.10.1 doesn't support IE8 !

Comment: Nop, it does http://bibwild.wordpress.com/2013/04/19/jquery-does-still-support-ie8-and-will-for-the-foreseeable-future/ . Also, it didn't work with 1.9.1, too.